# Do lambda expressions use reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

To be sure that I understand could someone confirm that lambda expressions use reflection?

Comment: No, they don't - but Linq (which is often used with Lambda expressions) does.

Comment: No. I don't think so.. Can you clarify the question a bit more...

Comment: LINQ doesn't necessarily use reflection either.

Comment: I can deny. They have nothing to do with reflection.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3844487/44620

Comment: Is the lack of types part of the confusion? Lambda expressions use type inference to determine the types of the parameters.

Comment: What for the problem to must be solved?

Comment: Lambda expressions are a simplification on top of delegate instantiations...

Comment: I think OP meant expression trees. In that case see [is-reflection-used-when-retrieving-information-from-a-linq-expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358618/is-reflection-used-when-retrieving-information-from-a-linq-expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can, but they are not required to. If they are compiled to a delegate, then no reflection is necessary: however, if they are compiled to ab expression tree, then an expression tree is **absolutely** reflection-based. Some parts of expression trees can be assembled directly from metadata tokens (ldtoken) - in particular methods (including operators and getters/setters, and types) - but some other parts **cannot** . This includes properties (`PropertyInfo` cannot be loaded by token) - so the IL for a compiled lambda can explicitly include `GetProperty` etc.

But however it is loaded (token or reflection), an expression tree **is** expressed in terms of reflection (`MemberInfo`, etc). This might later be compiled, or might be analysed by a provider.

To help performance, the expression compiler may cache some or all of the expression tree, and re-use it.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions are turned by the compiler into either anonymous functions or expression trees. Since reflection can only be performed at runtime it doesn't come into the picture at all when considering what the compiler does with them in either case.

At runtime, lambda expressions might result in reflection being used under very specific circumstances:

For anonymous functions: if you write an anonymous function that explicitly reflects on something then the lambda will perform that reflection when invoked. This is of course the same as if you were reflecting from within a "proper" method.

For expression trees (i.e. values of type [`Expression<TDelegate>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) for some `TDelegate`): using them at runtime when working with an `IQueryable` might result in reflection being used by the [query provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx). For example, assume that you do:

```
var user = new User { Id = 42 };
var posts = Queryable.Posts.Where(p => p.UserId == user.Id);
```

When `posts` is about to be materialized the query provider sees that it must find those posts with a `UserId` equal to the `Id` of the variable `user`. Since that id has a specific known value at runtime, the query provider needs to fish it out of `user`. One way it might decide to do that is through reflection.

Comment: Regardless of how it is used later, expression trees are fundamentally expressed in terms of reflection.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I can understand the reasoning, but OTOH if you get technical something like `Posts.Where(p => p.IsDeleted)` on EF won't result in actual reflection taking place... In any case I 'm open to suggestions if you feel the answer needs improvement.

Comment: it won't call GetValue etc, true: however, simply building the expression tree itself is: reflection-based

Comment: @MarcGravell: I agree with "reflection-based" or "reflection-oriented" as a description, *but*. It's the compiler that builds the tree, and since compiler != runtime (excluding expressly invoking compiler services etc) while reflection = runtime, it follows that compiler != reflection. In the end I feel that the one-word answer is "no" because it's not the expressions themselves that tap into reflection.

Comment: if you look at what the compiler emits, it is runtime reflection :)

Answer (score -1):

A lambda expressions is just compiler syntax sugar for creating delegates.  No reflection used here.

Comment: No, there are two possible outcomes from lambdas. Expression trees are fundamentally redlection-based.